# How do i smooth specific edges that went sharp when i edited a mesh?

Tags: modeling

[image: top unedited, bottom edited]

I'm editing a mesh from a game, I'm not sure how to edit it without a lot of the edges getting all sharp the moment I move things out of its original place, and i've looked everywhere and couldn't find an answer that didn't say to just shade smooth or simply can't be applied here. how do i smooth the specific spots that have been borked by me trying to edit it???

Comment: In edit mode, select the edges you want to clear sharps from, hit ctrl+e, and select clear sharp

Comment: Hello :). Just to add - shading is set *per face*. So you can select your faces and go *Face > Shade smooth*